# How to add share menu item to Gallery by code

Tags: android, intentfilter

I know how to implement this issue by Menuifest.xml, see also:

[Google Android Developer Group related issue](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/62a514363c751464/feecc033d0265606?lnk=gst&q=intentfilter+share#feecc033d0265606)

But my question is how to add share menu of Gallery by java code not Menuifest.xml.

My code is as below:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    try {
        intentFilter.addDataType("image/*");
    } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }

    Intent x = registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
            Log.d(TAG, "Received intent "+intent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context, Uploader.class));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        }, intentFilter);

    if (x==null)
        Log.i(TAG, "failed to regist a receiver");
    else
        Log.i(TAG, "registed a receiver successfully");
    // ...
```

But registerReceiver always return null, and there is no menu added to Gallery's Share.

Thank you.

Anthony Xu

Answer (score 1):

I asked this quest in google android developer group, and the android team member give me a reply:[thread in android group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ca183e0cbe0e1aec/34fa612bafd4c22f?lnk=gst&q=gallery#34fa612bafd4c22f)

Hope it help for you.